# Criar planilha adicionando imagens e trocando cor das linhas

Tags: php, array, microsoft-excel, xls

Este método cria uma planilha do Excel, com `int` e `string`:

```
public function arrayToXls($input) {
    // BoF
    $ret = pack('ssssss', 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);

    // array_values is used to ensure that the array is numerically indexed
    foreach (array_values($input) as $lineNumber => $row) {
        foreach (array_values($row) as $colNumber => $data) {
            if (is_numeric($data)) {
                // number, store as such
                $ret .= pack('sssssd', 0x203, 14, $lineNumber, $colNumber, 0x0, $data);
            } else {
                // everything else store as string
                $len = strlen($data);
                $ret .= pack('ssssss', 0x204, 8 + $len, $lineNumber, $colNumber, 0x0, $len) . $data;

            }
        }
    }


    //EoF
    $ret .= pack('ss', 0x0A, 0x00);

    return $ret;
}
```

Gostaria de adicionar uma imagem, poderiam auxiliar na alteração que preciso fazer nesta linha para isso?

```
$ret .= pack('ssssss', 0x204, 8 + $len, $lineNumber, $colNumber, 0x0, $len) . $data;
```

E também necessito trocar a cor da linhs

```
$ret .= pack('ss', 0x0A, 0x00);
```

Alguém tem alguma documentação ou já fez isto?

Comment: Não conheço muito php, mas se tiver utilizando Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer dê uma olhada em http://pear.php.net/manual/pt_BR/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.php, talvez ajude.

Answer (score 1):

Acabei optando pelo uso da biblioteca [PHP Excel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel)) .

Foi a maneira mais fácil de efetuar esta ação.

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais boba para criar uma planilha do Excel é modificar o cabeçalho da resposta e transformar a página em planilha:

```
$fileName = "planilha.xls";
header("Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
header("Content-type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$fileName");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: Ler a pergunta com atenção é a diferença entre passar no vestibular ou não (etc).

Comment: A solução resolve o problema. Com certeza não é a melhor forma, então, não entendi esse comentário besta brasofilo